# How do you implement context menu in a ListActivity on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, long-click

How do you implement a context menu triggered by a long click or tap on a ListActivity that is using the built in layouts and a ListAdapter?

Comment: Your edit has effectively changed the question entirely. Would probably have been better of just asking the different question.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

On the onCreate method call [registerForContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)) like this:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

and then populate the menu on [onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)). The menuInfo argument can provide information about which item was long-clicked in this way:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
try {
    info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
    return;
}
long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
```

and you add menu items in the usual way calling [menu.add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_ID, 0, R.string.menu_string);
```

and when the user picks an option, [onContextItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) is called. Also  [onMenuItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onMenuItemSelected(int,%20android.view.MenuItem)) and this fact is not explicitly explained in the documentation except to say that you use the other method to receive the calls from the context menu; just be aware, don't share ids.

On onContextItemSelected you can get ahold of the MenuInfo and thus the id of the item selected by calling [getMenuInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getMenuInfo()):

```
try {
    info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
    return false;
}
long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Been looking for that all over the Web but could only find old version. This one works perfect with cupcake.

Comment: I know that the ClassCastException guard code appears in the Google sample, but I think it's probably unnecessary. It's not likely that the MenuInfo is only sometimes an AdapterContextMenuInfo - it will probably always or never be. The guard clause stops the app from crashing, but you have a logic bug anyway. I'd personally rather see the whole stack trace, but that's just my preference.

Comment: @Daniel Yankowsky: If you use `registerForContextMenu` only only once: yes. But with a custom list activity layout you might have other elements to register as well. But then: Would it be not better to use `instanceof` and check what you got? — Ahh, well, I never seen any good demo code.

Answer (score 14):

You should also look at [Activity.registerForContextMenu(View)](http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)).

Answer (score 5):

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listpockets);
registerForContextMenu(listView);



public void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, View v, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    //AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.titleDelete));   
    menu.add(0, CommonUtil.CONTEXT_MENU__DELETE_ID, 0, getString(R.string.menuDelete));
};
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == CommonUtil.CONTEXT_MENU__DELETE_ID)
    {
       AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
       long id = this.listView.getItemIdAtPosition(info.position);
       Log.d(TAG, "Item ID at POSITION:"+id);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```