# Android ListView with clickable items in it's rows causes problems continuing scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, onclick, listadapter

I've been trawling the internet looking for an answer for several hours, but I can't seem to find anyone who has been able to solve this.

I've got a listview which uses a custom adapter. A row looks like this

[image]

The list is filled by an array. Everything works great.

Now, I want the ImageView and the ToggleButton to react to clicks, so I implement the OnClickListener in my adapter, put the items position in each view's tag, and then I set their onclicklistener to this.

Works great, except now I can't use the onListItemClick for starting an activity for the item! OK, I say, I just make the relativelayout holding the text in the middle there use the same onclicklistener. Works great. Everything is clickable, and life is good.

EXCEPT! Now, when I scroll the list, I cannot "continue" the scroll by just flinging again. This causes the scrolling to stop, and I have to fling once more to get it going again. It seems the onclick-thingy causes the fling-motion to be interpreted as a tap or something (it does not trigger the logic within onClick).

I know that this is possible by just going to the phone list on my HTC Hero, which has exactly the kind of layout and behaviour I want from my app. This app even seems to have the onItemClickListener working.

So how can I make sure the list keeps scrolling, and still be able to click the togglebutton, listitem and the imageview? I've been stuck on this all day, and it's giving me a headache :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another quick search before I go home, and I came across this:

[How to fire onListItemClick in Listactivity with buttons in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)

CodeFusionMobile mentions setting the `android:descendantFocusability` property of the list layout to `"blocksDescendants"`, and so I tried doing that. Everything works as expected now. Scrolling works, `onListitemClicked` works, clicking the `ToggleButton` works, clicking the `ImageView` works.

Just to make it clear... In the parent `RelativeLayout`, right at the top of the `row.xml`, I added

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```