# ListActivity extension doesn't execute onclick listener

Tags: android

I have an activity that extends ListActivity and implementsOnScrollListener:

```
public class RecentItemsList extends GenericListActivity implements OnScrollListener
```

and in this class I use a class that extends ArrayAdapter:

```
public class RecentItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
```

I'm trying to bind a callback when one of the items in the list is clicked by the user, but the callback isn't firing. Here's my code:

```
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnScrollListener(RecentItemsList.this);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,   int position, long id) {
                // do some stuff
            }
        });
```

But the OnItemClick event is never fired, but the scroll events fire properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific case, there were focusable views in my row. apparently not possible: [How to fire onListItemClick in Listactivity with buttons in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding your ListActivity's onListItemClick method instead:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick( ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{ 
//...
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also tried this, but didn't work. Does it matter that my ListActivity is part of a TabHost?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and resolved it by switching the type of activity we were extending.  I think we used ListActivity and listen to onListItemClick.