# Custom list view rows are not clickable

Tags: android

My custom `ListView` is not clickable. I am using `setOnItemClickListener`. My `ListView` row contains a button, image view and some textviews. Please help me make the items clickable.

Comment: add some code snippet.

Comment: try to find solution on web, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: set `android:focusable="false"` for all `View`s in your custom `ListView` item layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case if you use controls like `ImageButton`, `CheckBox` ,`Button` etc then you would face problems discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274231/listfragment-onlistitemclick-not-being-called) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list).
This is simply because such controls can steal **focus** from the `ListView` and the complete **list item** cant be selected/clicked.

I am assuming that you are using an Adapter to set the content of your list. Inside that adapter you can assign `onClickListener()`s for each item like this:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    .......
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View rowView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
         ImageView image=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
         image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //do something
            }
         }

         Button button=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //do something
            }
         }
         .......
    }
}
```

but remember that while using controls like `ImageButton`, `CheckBox` ,`Button` you need to assign property **`android:focusable="false"`** in the XML. and for the **`ImageButton`** you need to do this inside the `getView()` method:

```
    final ImageButton imgBtn=(ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
    imgBtn.setFocusable(false);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your task here
        }
    });
```

---

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

set clickable=false to all clickable views in listview row like (button).