# Communication between Fragments and ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I have two fragments in an activity and my first fragment is extending ListFragment class and there is one ListView widget whose id is 'list' in its xml layout. I wrote a custom adapter for this List and works fine but I need to click an item to pass some values to another fragment. For itemClick event I guess, I must use onListItemClick() method of ListFragment class.But when I run the app and click an item in list nothing happened.

```
public class List extends ListFragment {

    private Context context;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        KnlContainer knlModel = new KnlContainer();
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter((Activity)context,knlModel);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){

        super.onAttach(activity);
        context = activity;

      //I need to call this instance of interface to comminacation with Activity
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }

    }
    @Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

      // Send the event to the host activity

       //for comminacation with activity

        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
            Log.e("STAT","OK");
        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.knl_list_fragment, null);

        ListView knllrList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        knllrList.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        return rootView;

    }
}
```

I must define clicklistener in adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is purely for handling the data and generating the view for each row in the listview.

According to Android [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) API you **must** use *ListFragment.setListAdapter()*.

so....

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    KnlContainer knlModel = new KnlContainer();

    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter((Activity)context, knlModel));
 }
```

Comment: I fetched the data from adapter as you said but I want to add clicklistener to each item in listview becuase I need to show the results in another fragment by clicking these different items. When button click, it must call 
 public void onListItemClick but It doesnt work

Comment: If I am understanding you, you have a button for each item (row) in your ListView?

Comment: Yes, There is button in my custom row view but I dont know how use clicklistener. I must add clicklistener in my custom adapter? or I need to use onListItemClick() method of ListFragment ?

Comment: The button is unnecessary as the entire row view is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're list contains some other clickable element like a checkbox, you'll have to set it's `focusable` attribute to `false` before `onListItemClick` will work.

See this answer: [ListFragment OnListItemClick not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274231/listfragment-onlistitemclick-not-being-called)

---

If that doesn't work, another potential solution is to ensure the definition fo your`ListView`'s id is `android:id="android:id/list"` and **not** `android:id="@+id/list`.