# Adding onListItemLick/onItemLongClick in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter, onitemclicklistener

SOLVED IN A COMMENT: [Adding onListItemLick/onItemLongClick in a ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402628/adding-onlistitemlick-onitemlongclick-in-a-listfragment?noredirect=1#comment52674848_32402628)
The problem was generated from an `ImageButton` in the layout of the single element in the ListFragment that was stealing the input even with the `focusable` element set to false, so i had to remove it from the layout.

I've got a ListFragment populated by an extended class of SimpleCursorAdapter (mainly for overriding the newView method) but I wanted to add an AlertDialog when the user presses (or long presses) an item in the list the adapter generated.
I've tryed both `onListItemClick` and `onItemLongClick` with a simple log write using `Log.d` method but nothing happens in both cases and i don't know where is the problem since the code is really simple:

```
public class FragmentD extends ListFragment {

private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    myDatabase myDBHelper = new myDatabase(getActivity());
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Log.d("DB", "Insert fatto");

    String[] res_columns = new String[] {myDatabase.COLUMN2, myDatabase.COLUMN2,};
    String sortOrder = myDatabase.COLUMN1 + " DESC";

    String where = "*";

    Cursor testCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + database.DATABASE_TABLE, null);

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_element,
            testCursor,
            res_columns,
            new int[] { },
            0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
        Log.d("CLICK", "pressed");
    }
```

Comment: Try this; 

Change 

    onListItemClick

To 

    onItemClick

Comment: @Arrigo Pierotti...override it

Comment: I removed some extra stuff needed for implementing `onItemClick` instead of `onListItemClick` and the `@Override` was only missing when I copyed and pasted here.

Comment: can you post your layout?

Comment: There is really no general layout since this fragment is inside a `FragmentTabHost` and the layout of a single element (with `android:clickable=true` in the root element) is just 2 text views, one image and an image button

Comment: I found one thread in SO where they had similar problems where the components of the layout were stealing the input from other components. Check this, it might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274231/listfragment-onlistitemclick-not-being-called]

Comment: Thanks @JerrySangma! The ImageButton was "stealing" my input: changed to a normal ImageView made all the things work!

Comment: @Arrigo Pierotti welcome...you can now close the discussion by accepting the answer....I edited my previous answer below. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer:
    Maybe the components of the layout were stealing the input from other components of the layout

Comment: I removed some extra stuff needed for implementing `onItemClick` instead of `onListItemClick` and the `@Override` was only missing when I copyed and pasted here

Comment: Oh so it dosent work even if you override the method?

Comment: No, I edited the code in the question so it's the exact code I'm running on my emulator (there where extra stuff)

Comment: Forgot to add it here, my bad, but the super is in the code I'm testing now

Answer (score 0):

Add the super constructor and override it:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    Log.d("CLICK", "pressed");
}
```

EDIT: try this code

```
public class FragmentD extends ListFragment {

private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(YOUR LISTFRAGMENT LAYOUT HERE, container, false);

    myDatabase myDBHelper = new myDatabase(getActivity());
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Log.d("DB", "Insert fatto");

    String[] res_columns = new String[] {myDatabase.COLUMN2, myDatabase.COLUMN2,};
    String sortOrder = myDatabase.COLUMN1 + " DESC";

    String where = "*";

    Cursor testCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + database.DATABASE_TABLE, null);

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_element,
            testCursor,
            res_columns,
            new int[] { },
            0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    Log.d("CLICK", "pressed");
}
```

Comment: I removed the implement and the getListView since they where for `onItemClick` and the @override was missing only here (i had to do a little edit when i copyed and pasted here) but nothing has changed, still no sign in the Log...

Comment: You forgot the super constructor and remove this -> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: The super constructor has been added (my bad for not adding it in the code at the beginning) and still not works

Comment: Remove the implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener. Any ListFragment needs only to override the onListItemClick method to make it work

Comment: Sorry for all the things I forget to change in the code up here, but even without this implement it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have got two solution

1. Simply Override onListItemClick

   @Override
   public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

   ```
     Log.i("position",position);
   ```

   }
2. On the root layout. Add this code

   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Hope it helps

Comment: I removed some extra stuff needed for implementing `onItemClick` instead of `onListItemClick` and the `@Override` was only missing when I copyed and pasted here