# listview item selection having custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a problem in selecting an item from a listview which gets inflated by a custom list adapter. I tried adding a onitemclicklistener it did not work. I even tried logging the click listener, nothing showed up in the logcat. Anyone help me knowing where the mistake is.

the adapter used,

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

and the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://somewebsite.php";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });

                    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

someone let me know where the error is.Thanks.

Comment: try applying listner inside adapter to your layout.

Comment: @Punith see my answer on this thread.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402628/adding-onlistitemlick-onitemlongclick-in-a-listfragment/32402888#32402888]

Answer (score 0):

if onItemClickListener is not working then go to custom xml layout which you created for Row in Listview if there is checkbox or imageview write in there tage     android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: yes..there is an image view in the custom row xml layout..can u be still more clear..i dint get y