# Android: cannot set both: setOnItemClickListener setOnScrollListener?

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener,  OnItemClickListener {
...
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
listView.setOnScrollListener(this);  // why not work with previous line?
...
```

After adding ListView.setOnScrollListener(this)

onItemClick(...) no longer triggered.

Anybody know why?

thanks.

Comment: tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list
added on row.xml

android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

still not working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it shouldn't work,

Try this :

```
  getListView().setOnScrollListener(onAnswersScrolled);
  getListView().setOnItemClickListener(onAnswerClicked);
```

---

```
private OnItemClickListener onAnswerClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // 
                Intent i = new Intent();

                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
        }

    };

    private OnScrollListener onAnswersScrolled = new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // not used
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // do something
            }
        }
    };
```

<sub>[source](http://droidstack.googlecode.com/hg/src/org/droidstack/activity/AnswersActivity.java?r=655732b91adf7137c88ed3b5c67f9510ec4fb619)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is my code to display a customized listView. It works for me.

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener  {

MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(this);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(adapter); 
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /**Original holder
         * 
         * 
         * */
        //ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder=new ViewHolder();  

        }else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class myButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;


        myButtonListener(int pos) {
            position = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int vid=v.getId();

        }
    }

}
```

hope it helps.