# getLayoutInflater inside custom simpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, layout, adapter

I'm stuck with creating custom adapter. I want to setOnClickListener on the buttons inside ListView and I found this topic which looks ok [how-to-setonclicklistener-on-the-button-inside-the-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121476/how-to-setonclicklistener-on-the-button-inside-the-listview) but the problem is that I'm getting unreachable code error on the getLayoutInflater line.

here is my code

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private final Context ctx;
    private Button tagButton = null;

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = li.inflate(R.layout.tags_list_element, null, true);
        tagButton= (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tag_title);
        tagButton.setTag(position);

        tagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            }
        });
        return rowView;

    }

}
```

both methods doesn't work for me

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
```

and

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Can u plz show me the error Log...........

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
View myView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
```

Moreover, what exception do you get?

---

Edit: In your "getView" method, the first line is "return.....", so the rest of your method won't ever be executed, I think.... ;)

Comment: Ye I missed the return on the beginning.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

From a performance point of view:

```
View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);
```

Is correct; but its more efficient to store the inflater in an final field inside the adapter.

```
private final Context ctx;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Button tagButton = null;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
          String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    ctx = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
}
```

Then do your getView operation.

```
//....
final View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
//....
//stuff here
//
return v;
```

ALSO make sure you Context is your Activity Context, you will get Theming issues if you use the wrong context.

Regards,
Chris