# onItemClick is not working if there is Button in the item view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

This is an item of my `ListView`:

[image]

The star is a `Button`. I set a `OnClickListener` for it in `getView()` method of the `Adapter`. But I now face a problem - `onItemClick` doesn't fire after adding the `Button`. I want a `Button` to listen for its clicks and the rest part of a view to respond with firing `onItemClick`. Is there a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: hey bluebyte. Did you overcome this problem. I have the same isssue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but Button is not working in list item , so plz use ImageView instead of Button.
You can also set onClick on ImageView same as Button in your getView() method

```
ImageView.setOnClickListener().....etc
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the button not focusable (but still clickable):

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked this but it not worked. Button works. OnChildItemClick not

Answer (score 0):

If you put `onClickListener()` on an item in `getView()` of Adapter , then `onItemClickListener()` in that Activity doesn't work. For this you can put `onClickListener()` on your star button and put all other Items in a Layout and put `onClickListener()` in `getView()` to that layout.