# Android: Layout doesn't change background on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Have following piece of layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/colleagues_show_email_linearLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:background="?attr/clickableItemBackground">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/colleagues_show_email_textView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i click on ImageView, LinearLayout changes background the same way as in the ListView. But clicking on TextView doesn't change background. What's wrong?

**Update**
I had a View.OnClickListener (with only onClick(View v) {Log.d(TAG, "Email onClick"); }) on the TextView and that was the issue. After removing setOnClickListener line it starts to work as expected.

Comment: Please share the code where you write the code to change the background color

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper, android:background="?attr/clickableItemBackground" attribute on LinearLayout.

Comment: Set the textview height and width to wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

Set the textview height and width to wrap_content.

Comment: I think the textview is not visible so textview click not working. You need to set property android:text="Sample Text" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textsize="25sp"

Comment: No, it was visible with text (i set it via java code).

Comment: Can you please send the code so that i can properly verify and resolve errors

Comment: Thanks for your patience. See updated question now. I still don't know how to fix this issue with onClickListener but it works without it.

Comment: _textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
             Log.d(TAG, "Email onClick"); 
                
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

**To change the colour of the layout**

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(
            Color.parseColor("your colourcode(ex.#AE00FF)"));

    }
});
```

**To get the colour**

```
ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) listview.getBackground();
int colorCode = cd.getColor();
```

Comment: What i want to do is not setting colour on click.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` has no click event but the `TextView` handles the click event on its own. When you tap it, it allows you to edit the text inside. You are actually not clicking on the List item, so it doesn't execute the List selector. You will have to manage to fire the List item `onClick` event from the `TextView`, probably from the `TextView`'s `onClick` event... or maybe [THIS THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list) could help also. It suggests using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your layout.

Good luck

Comment: I don't have list item here. Just style from it.

Comment: it's basically the same, you have a layout with selector background. You need to handle the `TextView`s `onClick` to simulate click on the linear layout