# button on listview i want to use button.setonclicklistener and onListItemClick what i need to do

Tags: android, list, view

i want to use button.setonclicklistener and onListItemClick what i need to do

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789943/using-android-how-can-i-select-rows-from-a-listview-which-contains-button-contro/3791340#3791340

Answer (score 0):

Set focusable of the button to false, and both of them will work.

```
button.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: if i use trackball what i need to do