# Android ListView - onListItemClick does not work properly

Tags: java, android, listactivity, android-listview

I created a ListView in Android, and a corresponding ListActivity. Each individual item in the ListView has just one TextView (I plan to add an image and a CheckBox later).The ListActivity overrides the  onListItemClick to perform certain tasks on click of any item on the list.

Heres whats happening -

- When I first tried clicking on any item, nothing happened.
- I then tried setting the properties "Focusable" and "Focusable in Touch Mode" to false for the TextView, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789943/using-android-how-can-i-select-rows-from-a-listview-which-contains-button-contro/3791340#3791340), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611551/textview-and-button-in-each-row-and-onlistitemclick) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items). The List items started recognizing clicks, but only when I clicked somewhere away from the TextView. Whenever I tried clicking on the TextView or anywhere near it, it did not work.
- I also tried changing various attributes like Clickable, but nothing has worked so far.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set `setItemsCanFocus=false` on the ListView itself, as described in the first link?

Comment: Yes Dan, I tried that too, did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with virtually every attribute in my TextView, I finally found the reason why it was not working. It was because of the attribute android:inputType="text" in my TextView. I'm not sure why I added that piece of code (I probably copied the TextView from one of my other applications), but removing it solves my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I had the same problem and didn't think at all that inputType="text" could be the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Class which will listen clicks on `ListView` should implement interface  `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`