# ListView with ImageButton

Tags: android

I am new on android developing and I am meat a problem trying to associate a ListView with Buttons on the row.I am declaring the button in my adapter but I cant fire a key listener in my activity.

```
public class ntAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.AddBut=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
}
```

In my activity I have a listview

```
public class Zmenu extends Activity {
    ntAdapter adapter=new ntAdapter(this);

    ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    l1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What is the code in this case to have a key listener on my image Button??

Comment: are you actually trying to listen to clicks / touches on that button?

Comment: what key listener? do you mean clickListener?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Using Android, how can I select rows from a ListView which contains Button controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789943/)

And make use of [the View Holder Pattern](http://books.google.com/books?id=2XeNswkT_2YC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=android%20view%20holder%20pattern&source=bl&ots=on4-D63wIW&sig=IKXVnLDT-sgKxWp2_wQrNuoBIcQ&hl=en&ei=PuuxTdLFC46usAP_uuD7Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false).