# Accessible way to click both ListView row and Button in row?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

It's easy to make a row in a ListView do something when it is clicked. But add something else in the row--such as a Button or other control--that has an OnClickListener, and suddenly nothing happens when the row is clicked.

Before you close this question as a duplicate, I am perfectly aware that there are a number of StackOverflow questions about that. They generally either recommend setting the Button android:focusable="false" or setting android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the ViewGroup containing the row Views.

These work, but one problem: if you're navigating with the keyboard (tabbing or arrow keys), it skips right over the Button.

Is there a way to solve the issue and allow people to "click" either row or Button without having to actually tap the touchscreen?

Comment: implement button clickListener for every row and created in Adapter.

Comment: For this you need to implement click listener for both button and main parent view of each row, it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an OnClickListener on each row (instead of setting an item click listener for the ListView) did not help.

I did find some more info, such as using ListView.setItemsCanFocus(true) [Using Android, how can I select rows from a ListView which contains Button controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789943/using-android-how-can-i-select-rows-from-a-listview-which-contains-button-contr/3791340#3791340) and using beforeDescendants [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview) but can't get both the row and the button to be usable with a keyboard.

BUT it occurred to me to try and test out Gmail with a keyboard. I can't find a way to mark a row as a favorite (select the star). So apparently even they aren't making it fully accessible! Oh well. A lose cause I suppose.