# registerForContextMenu not get calling properly - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: android

The answer to this question might be really obvious but its giving me a headache. I have a simple LinearLayout with one single ListView in it. I do this: onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.friends);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friend_list);
        listAdapter = new CheckinListAdapter(checkins, listView, R.layout.checkin_list_item);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            FriendsActivity last = (FriendsActivity) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            this.checkins.addAll(last.checkins);
            this.sort = last.sort;
        } else {
            refresh();
        }
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
    }
```

But for some reason `onCreateContextMenu` never gets called! So I did some research and since I am loading the list after the register, perhaps it doesn't register it correctly. If I go in my `ListAdapter` and do `registerForContextMenu` it does show up. But it doesn't behave correctly with the keyboard. So I am now confused on what can be the error because it seems a little non intuitive for me to have to register each child item. All the examples I find online are using `ArrayAdapter`. :(

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

**Here is more detail, in case it something I don't see:**

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:text="@string/check_in"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCheckInClicked"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/friend_list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

List item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/user_photo"
               android:layout_width="40dip"
               android:layout_height="40dip"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="8dip">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/user" style="@style/TextButton"/>

            <TextView android:text="@string/at"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/venue"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    style="@style/TextButton"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/venue_address" style="@style/GreyLarge"/>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/checkin_detail"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                      android:layout_marginBottom="6dip">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/checkin_image"
                       android:layout_width="70dip"
                       android:layout_height="60dip"
                       android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
                       android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/checkin_shout"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/elapsedTime" style="@style/GreySmall"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This took me 6 hours to figure out but it turns out I had to add:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

to all my `<Button/>` tags.

Related post: [TextView and Button in each row and onListItemClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611551/textview-and-button-in-each-row-and-onlistitemclick/3611898#3611898)

Comment: In my case, the list item had a check box. Context menu did not work initially but it worked once I set focusable to false for the check box.

Answer (score 0):

Do, registerForContextMenu(listView); 
before setting the adapter, that is before:

listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

You have mentioned that the menu is not responding correctly with the keyboard actions. Can you tell me what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Hi Swathi - I moved registerForContextMenu right after findViewById() and I still don't see anything happening. What I meant before was by using the scroll wheel I am not able to get the context menu opened. But by using the mouse I can click and hold to open. This is the sample I have used https://github.com/mikeplate/ListViewDemo

Comment: Hi Amir, As i know, context menu will be displayed when we perform long press on a view.This link may help you- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html