# ExpandableListView OnLongClick not recognized by listener

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onlongclicklistener

I have tried several different combinations (comments below are fragments of this). Debug doesn't recognize the click as ever happening. The item highlights, but nothing happens. I have tried inflating the custom row.xml file and using the views inside row layout file as well. No exceptions, no more ideas. Thanks for looking.

*Also, I realize the onCreateContextMenu method is a little light. I just want to get the thing to pop up, then I will take care of the details!*

**Main Activity**

```
public class BrowseActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);

    final ExpandableListView browseView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    DbHelper dbh = new DbHelper(BrowseActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME);

    Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(db, new String[] { Items.ITEMS_ID,
            Items.ITEMS_ITEM, Items.ITEMS_DESC }, null, null, null, null,
            Items.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    CursorTreeAdapter mAdapter = new MyExpandabaleListAdapter(this,
            mCursor, R.layout.row, R.layout.exprow, new String[] {
                    Items.ITEMS_ITEM, Items.ITEMS_DESC }, new int[] {
                    R.id.txtItem, R.id.dscItemTwo }, new String[] {
                    Items.ITEMS_DESC, Items.ITEMS_MANU }, new int[] {
                    R.id.dscItem, R.id.manuItem });

    browseView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());

}

public class MyExpandabaleListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    public MyExpandabaleListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c,
            int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom,
            int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) {

        super(context, c, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout,
                childrenFrom, childrenTo);

    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {...}

}

public void OnCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

     menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Add");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add("Add Item").setIntent(new Intent(this, AddItemActivity.class));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return false;
}
```

}

**browse layout** *This is the layout the holds the ELV.*

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/expandLinLayout"
 >
 <ExpandableListView 
 android:id = "@android:id/list" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:groupIndicator="@drawable/my_group_statelist"  
 >  
 </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row layout** *This is the collapsed layout.*

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" 
android:id="@+id/txtItem" 
android:text="Item" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:textSize="15dip"

></TextView>


 <TextView 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" 
android:id="@+id/dscItemTwo" 
android:text="Desciption" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:textStyle="italic"
android:textColor="#666666"

></TextView>
```

**exprow layout** *This is the expanded layout.*

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
<TextView 
android:layout_gravity="right" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/manuItem" 
android:textColor="#994020" 
android:text="Manufacturer"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
></TextView>

<TextView 
android:text="Description"
android:id = "@+id/dscItem"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
 android:textColor="#994020" 
></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: am I being dumb, but where's the long click method?

Comment: I doubt you are being dumb, I'm the one with a handicap of 26. I was under the assumption that it was included in the registerForContextMenu(), I think I read that somewhere...??..

Comment: Ah yes, why have you commented out registering the context ontou your list and now instead inflate some other view? I think this is your error.

Comment: That was me trying two different options. I don't like to delete ideas until I know they won't work! If I uncomment it, it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Background reading](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

In your [registerForContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29)()do you not have to pass in the declared list:

```
 registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView()](http://getListView%20API)

or in your case:

[http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html#getExpandableListView()](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html#getExpandableListView%28%29)

StackOvflow reference: [How do you implement context menu in a ListActivity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433761/how-do-you-implement-context-menu-in-a-listactivity-on-android)

Comment: This wouldn't work for me. After 9 hours I gave in and used setOnCreateContextMenuListener() in place of registerForContextMenu() and onCreateContextMenu(). Works fine now, not sure why, but it works.