# How to implement a listener for ExpandableListView release after a longItemClick

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

In my project I need to do some action when releasing an `ExpandableListView` item after a `OnLongClick` event. How to do this? Can any one give a simple example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636442/expandablelistview-onlongclick-not-recognized-by-listener

Comment: This is some what complicated, right? can you mention any other resource? I had searched a lot, but none of them was seem as useful. more over I new in android development.

Comment: My self found a great quesiton @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145172/android-listview-running-an-event-on-item-long-click-release

Answer (score 0):

```
expandableListview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id);

          if ( itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
              childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
              groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);

              //do your per-item callback here
              return true; //true if we consumed the click, false if not

          } else if(itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
              groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
              //do your per-group callback here
              return true; //true if we consumed the click, false if not

          } else {
              // null item; we don't consume the click
              return false;
          }
  });
```