# Create context menu without ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, android-linearlayout

I wanted to create a context menu in my app. But its difficult without `ListActivity`.
I have a `FragmantActivity` with a `ViewPager`, and the `ViewPager`'s adapter contains a few views which extend `LinearLayout`. Those `LinearLayout` views contain a list view.

So how can I create a `ContextMenu` in a class which extends `LinearLayout` ?

so here is the class i mentiond, i cleared the code, just showing the listview which i wanted to have a context menu

```
public class Days extends LinearLayout {

public Days(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String day) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(day);
}
public Days(Context context, String day) {
    super(context);
    init(day);
}
private void init(String day) {
    final ListView lv = new ListView(getContext());
    lv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    Adapter adapter = new CustomListviewAdapter(getContext(), orak);
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);   
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

addView(lv, params);
}
```

and here is the viewpager adapter class where i add this layout

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<LinearLayout> views;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        views = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
        views.add(new Days(context, "Monday"));
                     ......... etc..

    }
```

and this viewpager is in a simple activity

If anyone knows the answer, please help.

Answer (score 0):

What's the link between listActivity and context menus ?
Can't you just register your view for context menus as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433761/how-do-you-implement-context-menu-in-a-listactivity-on-android) ?

Comment: as i said i dont have a listactivity

Comment: sorry i misunderstanded it, so i knew that its only possible in lisactivitys, i will take a look at your link

Comment: no i cant use the registerForContextMenu(getListView());
because the views are added in the viewpagers adapter, which is another class, so i have to do it in the linearlayout.