# How can I set an on onListItemLongClick to list from database?

Tags: android, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I want to show a layout which contain (edit & delete ) so when user *longClick* on an item of the list he will get a dialog to choose if he want to delete or to edit this item
how can I do that ? and thinks

```
public class MissionAct extends ListActivity {
      private DbaseManager datasource;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addmission_activity);
        datasource = new DbaseManager(this);
        datasource.open(getBaseContext());
        List<Missions> values = datasource.getAllMissions();
        ArrayAdapter<Missions> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Missions>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
        this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adpter, View v, int position, long id) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialg);
                dialog.setTitle("Nouveau point");
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });                      
 }
          }
```

and the error Log is

```
04-29 13:42:45.048: E/Babel(31576): canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
04-29 13:42:46.067: E/dalvikvm(31611): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method box.a
04-29 13:42:46.957: E/CellLocation(30121): create GsmCellLocation
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245): mtprof entry can not found!
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.mtProf(ActivityRecord.java:852)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:653)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:225)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:6994)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:754)
04-29 13:42:47.412: E/ActivityManager(245): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it like this;

```
this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Message?");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               //Edit
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               //Delete
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.create().show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

And you can use position as index to access list element.

Comment: no dont work
fatal exeption android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Could you try creating a global variable Context mContext = this; And use mContext this line AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `OnItemLongClickListener` for the `ListView` like this, So that when an item is long clicked `onItemLongClick` will be called

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)      { 
            // do your other stuff here based on the list item position
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: dont work 
fatal exeption android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an applicati

Comment: i edited the question so now i puted the edited code and the error log

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

[`OnLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) and [`getListView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29)

```
getListView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

you can use `Context Menu` also refer below examples

[How do you implement context menu in a ListActivity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433761/how-do-you-implement-context-menu-in-a-listactivity-on-android)

[Using contextmenu with listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632331/using-contextmenu-with-listview-in-android)

http://www.tktutorials.com/2013/06/android-context-menu-example.html

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //set your dialog here
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: dont work 
fatal exeption android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an applicati